# Use 'and' or a comma in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, expressions, differences

The sentence is 'The rabbit led the lion to a deep, wide river.'

Can I say 'deep and wide' here instead? Any difference in meaning?

I have been always taught that linking 2 things should use the word 'and'. More than 3 things use 'a, b and c' pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, you can use *and* and it wouldn't change the meaning.

Your sentence is an example of the use of *coordinate adjectives.*

This is discussed by *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 6.36:

> As a general rule, when a noun is preceded by two or more adjectives that could, without affecting the meaning, be joined by *and*, the adjectives are separated by commas. Such adjectives, which are called coordinate adjectives, can also usually be reversed in order and still make sense . . .
>
> Shelly had proved a faithful, sincere friend. (Shelly’s friendship has proved faithful *and* sincere.)
> It is going to be a long, hot, exhausting summer. (The summer is going to be long *and* hot *and* exhausting.)